# C++ function pointer in class

Tags: c++, function, pointers

```
class Solution
{
public:
  bool cmp(int a, int b)
  {
    return a>b;
  }
  int noo(vector<int>& v)
  {
    sort(v.begin() , v.end() , &Solution::cmp);
    return 0;
  }
};
```

it will not work if I call the function noo.
But if I kick cmp out of my function, it will work fine (obviously...)
What is problem and how do I write function pointer here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass to sort predicate that is a member function, from the constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20924450/how-to-pass-to-sort-predicate-that-is-a-member-function-from-the-constructor)

Comment: Make your `cmp()` member function static. Duh!

Comment: You want to sort the integers in descending order? Use `sort(v.rbegin(), v.rend())`, which would use the default `less<int>` for comparison.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think making (cmp )function global will resolve your problem, if you want it to be class member do mark it as static.

Comment: This work, but can you be kind enough to explain why static is necessary?